# position: absolute; in my hero image doesn´t let me add more content

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

Link to the site is

I have an image with size cover as soon as you enter the page. In order to make it available in every browser (I was having troubles with Opera mini and Android browser) I added this code to the div element:

```
 .portada{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px 10px 60px 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0; 
      background: url(../img/nike.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    /* background-attachment: fixed; removed for Android */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, now, because of the position: fixed; when I keep adding content into my page, bellow that section, it displays under the picture and I can´t see it. It is destroying my page. And as soon as I take out the position: fixed; code, it goes back to not displaying the image full screen in Opera and old Android browser.

I want to be able to create more content and scroll down the page.

I have tried with position:relative; but it goes back to not working on Opera mini. It displays the image full width but with minimum height.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the solution. I added to the .portada class  min-height: 300px; and now at least in those browsers the image is a little bit bigger and it does the job. I also took out the width and height properties so the final code of the class is:

```
 .portada{
position: relative;
min-height: 300px;
z-index: -1;
padding: 20px 10px 60px 10px;
height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/nike.jpg) no-repeat center center;
/* background-attachment: fixed; removed for Android */
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Looks like it works good in every browser I can test.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you display your image as a background and your div.portdata is empty. Try inserting the image using `img` html tag.